# Java - sorting an alphanumerical list with double values

Tags: sorting, double, comparator, alphanumeric

I'm having a problem with sorting an alphanumerical list, which contains both letters, integer and double values. Looked all over the place for an answer, but they could not help in my case as my list would be sorted in the wrong manner, so I'm asking for your help.
Consider having a list of strings: [-2.2, 2.2, 2.2, -22, -22, -22, -1.1, qqqq]. My goal is to have this list sorted in ascending order with letters going to the back. `Collections.sort()` method provided me with the following sorted list: [-1.1, -2.2, -22, -22, -22, 2.2, 2.2, qqqq] which is far from what I am looking for. I also tried the following example from stackoverflow:

```
    public class ComparatorClass{
    final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\d+");
    String[] examples = {"-2.2", "2.2", "2.2", "-22", "-22", "-22", "-1.1", "qqqq"};

    public void go() {
        Comparator<String> c = new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String object1, String object2) {
                Matcher m = p.matcher(object1);
                Double number1 = null;
                if (!m.find()) {
                    return object1.compareTo(object2);
                } else {
                    Double number2 = null;
                    number1 = Double.parseDouble(m.group());
                    m = p.matcher(object2);
                    if (!m.find()) {
                        return object1.compareTo(object2);
                    } else {
                        number2 = Double.parseDouble(m.group());
                        int comparison = number1.compareTo(number2);
                        if (comparison != 0) {
                            return comparison;
                        } else {
                            return object1.compareTo(object2);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        List<String> examplesList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(examples));

        Collections.sort(examplesList, c);
        System.out.println(examplesList);
    }
}
```

Sadly, this one also gave me the same answer as `Collections.sort()` method. I need an answer of [-22, -22, -22, -2.2, -1.1, 2.2, 2.2, qqqq]. 
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using a strategy where you isolate text and numerical comparisons separately.  This makes the logic much less confusing.  For mixed cases, i.e. where one string to be compared is text, and the other a number, the logic is clear about how to sort.

```
Comparator<String> c = new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        boolean b1 = s1.matches(".*[^0-9.\\-].*");
        boolean b2 = s2.matches(".*[^0-9.\\-].*");

        // if both are bona fide doubles
        if (!b1 && !b2) {
            Double d1 = Double.parseDouble(s1);
            Double d2 = Double.parseDouble(s2);

            return d1.compareTo(d2);
        }
        // if both are text, then compare as strings
        else if (b1 && b2) {
            return s1.compareTo(s2);
        }
        // otherwise return one or the other, depending on which is text/number
        else return b2 ? -1 : 1;
    }
};
```

Comment: Precisely! Thank you very much!